# Unable to remove malware, even after factory reset and system flash. Sony Xperia 1 IV, XQ-CT72

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, malware, sony-xperia, virus

I had a rooted phone, in which I misclicked an apk and installed it. Almost immediately I uninstalled it and disabled the network (I also had afwall and netguard enabled). However it was too late. I got a ~100's of 0kb system apps without icons. I re-flashed the phone with fresh stock firmware and factory reset it, however the broken system apps (and likely the malware) are still there.

Does anyone have suggestions on what can be done to fix this? Or any knowledge of similar malware?

Some antivirus I could use, or maybe something stronger than a system flash?

Thanks in advance.

[image: After factory reset and flash]

Picture after factory reset and flash.

Comment: Where do you got the stock firmware image from? Are you sure it is genuine? Are you sure the rro packages are really malware, because Android knows such packages that are loaded using an file-system overlay: https://source.android.com/docs/core/runtime/rros?hl=en

Comment: I got the stock firmware from XperiFirm 5.7.0 (by Igor Eisberg), I am pretty sure it's genuine. I am very sure these are malware because there are 0 kb system apps with version 1, that only got installed when I installed the malware.

Comment: Do you still have the .APK file which you installed? I'd be interested in taking a look at it.

Comment: No, It's been deleted sadly.